# Fading Latest News Ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to get the most efficient way to produce a latest news ticker.

I have a `ul` which can hold any number of `li`'s and all I need to to loop through them fading one in, holding it for 5 seconds and then fading it out, one `li` at a time. The list is displaying with an `li` height of 40px and the well it displays in is also 40px which with `overflow: hidden` which produces the desired effect. Also to be able to hold the `li` in place if the cursor hovers over it while its being displayed would be great to build it.

I know there is the jQuery ticker plugin that is widely used (ala the old BBC style) but I've tried to use it and it seems so bulky for the simplicity I need and it plays havoc with the styling I use.

I've been using this so far:

```
function tickOut(){
        $('#ticker li:first').animate({'opacity':0}, 1000, function () { 
            $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).css('opacity', 1); });

    }

    setInterval(function(){ tickOut () }, 5500);
```

But it doesn't actually fade in the next `li` so the effect is a bit messy.

If someone could suggest some alternations to help produce the effect I need that would be so useful.

Thanks

Comment: could you provide fiddler.net example, please?

Comment: Suppose @LorDex talking about http://jsfiddle.net actually

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KFyzq/ - works fine for me here

Comment: here is the exact example http://jsfiddle.net/9gQRP/

Comment: Issue is not that it doesn't work, its that it doesn't fade **in** and doesn't pause if the cursor moves over the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hide()` and call `fadein()` the element after it becomes the top of the list.

```
function tickOut(){
        $('#ticker li:first').animate({'opacity':0}, 1000, function () {
            $(this).appendTo($('#ticker'))
            $('#ticker li:first').hide()
            $('#ticker li:first').fadeIn(1000)
              $('#ticker li:not(:first)').css('opacity', '1')
        });
    }

setInterval(function(){ tickOut () }, 5500);
```

see:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lHdGb

Comment: It achives the fading effect but running the .hide() removes the li's from the page and so it won't cycle :(

Comment: Didnt know you wanted a loop, i have updated the codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lHdGb) is that any better?

Comment: Store the interval in a variable and call clearInterval in a mouse over event listener. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I woudl do it like that:

```
function tickOut(){
    $('#ticker li:first').animate({'opacity':0}, 1000, function () { 
            $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).css('opacity', 1); });
    }
var interval;
$(function() {
    interval = setInterval(function(){ tickOut () }, 5500);
    $('#ticker').hover(function() {
             if(interval)
                 clearInterval(interval);
             $('#ticker li:first').stop();   
             $('#ticker li:first').css('opacity', 1).stop();  
         }, function(){
             interval = setInterval(function(){ tickOut () }, 5500);
             });
});
```

See [`$('#ticker').hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which clears interval and stops animation and returns `opacity` to 1 when mouse got inside `UL` (may be changed to do that when only some special element inside `LI` is under mouse) and starts it again once it left that `UL`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KFyzq/6/